# Best method of downloading a folder of content from multiple versions of SharePoint from .NET

Tags: client-object-model, download

I need to implement some code which, given a specific site URL and folder, will download all files within that folder and any sub-folders. I know I can use the SharePoint Client SDK for that, but one thing that I cannot find is whether the 2013 SDK will work against older versions of SharePoint, or whether I need to have multiple implementations and detect what version of SharePoint the user has pointed at.

Also, I'm sure that the client SDK is overkill for what I'm using, because it seems like a very simple use case.

So, my question is, what is the best method to facilitate downloading a folder of content from multiple versions of SharePoint from .NET?

Comment: Have you considered SkyDrive Pro (OneDrive for Business)?

Comment: If it's a basic http address you might just use something like xcopy

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have been clearer. I maintain an app which is shipped to customers which does analysis of data from various sources. I would like my customers to be able to analyze data (currently only Excel files) stored on SharePoint, so I can't mandate that they have a particular side-product, if you like.